# Unable to get the text values from the options of the dropdown using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class DellDropdown {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        driver.get("http://www.dell.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ctryName']")).click();
        WebElement countryDropdown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='para_small']"));
        Select selectElement = new Select(countryDropdown);
        selectElement.selectByVisibleText("India");
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ctryName' and text()='India']")).getText().equals("India")){
            System.out.println("The dropdown is changed to india");
        }
        WebElement selectedCountryDropdown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='para_small']"));
        selectElement = new Select(selectedCountryDropdown);
        List<WebElement> options=selectElement.getOptions();
        for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++){
            WebElement option=options.get(i);
            String countryName=option.getText();
            boolean selectedValue=option.isSelected();
            System.out.print(countryName);
            System.out.println(selectedValue);
        }
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

On selecting country India from the country dropdown in the dell site
I am not getting the text from the option tag of the dropdown only the selected status is returned.Kindly let me know how to get the text?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Rewritting my answer to make it clearer

The problem is that the options in the select dropdown don't contain any texts, when the select dropdown is closed. You only get to see which option is selected:

```
<select class="para_small" name="" size="20" data-index="75">
<option value="/aa/en/gen/df.aspx?refid=df&s=gen&~ck=cr"></option>
<option value="/al/en/gen/df.aspx?refid=df&s=gen&~ck=cr"></option>
<option value="/dz/fr/gen/df.aspx?refid=df&s=gen&~ck=cr"></option>
...
<option value="/in/en/gen/df.aspx?refid=df&s=gen" selected="selected"></option>
...
</select>
```

What you need to do is to click and open that dropdown again, after you select "India" and the page gets reloaded.

This is how you can do it:

```
// the fix
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ctryName']")).click();
// end of fix
```

And here is your full code with my fix to show you where it is done:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class DellDropdown {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        driver.get("http://www.dell.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ctryName']")).click();
        WebElement countryDropdown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='para_small']"));
        Select selectElement = new Select(countryDropdown);
        selectElement.selectByVisibleText("India");
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ctryName' and text()='India']")).getText().equals("India")){
            System.out.println("The dropdown is changed to india");
        }

        // the fix
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ctryName']")).click();
        // end of fix

        WebElement selectedCountryDropdown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='para_small']"));
        selectElement = new Select(selectedCountryDropdown);
        List<WebElement> options=selectElement.getOptions();
        for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++){
            WebElement option=options.get(i);
            String countryName=option.getText();
            boolean selectedValue=option.isSelected();
            System.out.print(countryName);
            System.out.println(selectedValue);
        }
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

**NOTE: Make sure you don't interfere with the brower while the test is running, otherwise your mouse movement will generate an `onmouseout` event and the dropdown will close and the text values will disappear!**

**EDIT:** To make sure the select dropdown stays open, you can move the mouse to that dropdown in each iteration of the options loop. However that solution slows down the code, so you have to choose what suits you best.

Moving the mouse in the "for" loop:

```
    for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++){
        //fix
        Actions mouseAction = new Actions(driver);
        mouseAction.moveToElement(selectedCountryDropdown).build().perform();
        //end of fix

        WebElement option=options.get(i);
        String countryName=option.getText();
        boolean selectedValue=option.isSelected();
        System.out.print(countryName);
        System.out.println(selectedValue);
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply....I am getting this exception on running your program @papacito:Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[0] is undefined...Can you tell me how i should handle this?

Comment: I switched to `FirefoxDriver` and on firefox my code works even without the javascript trick, so try commenting out those two lines where `JavascriptExecutor` is used.

Comment: In ff, i do not get the country names from the dropdown I only get the selected status(like my code)....When do you use JavaScriptExecutor?....executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element); what is arguments[0].click();"?......why are you using element.click(); and this executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);? don't they have the same behaviour?

Comment: Ok, see my edit above for showing the country names. What I did before  with the `JavascriptExecutor` was to make it work on Chrome and on Firefox it turned out to be unnecessary. It is indeed duplicating the click action, but seems to help with the stubborn select dropdowns :)

Comment: Actually I should clean up my answer and remove the initial changes as what is really relevant is what I wrote in the "edit"...

Comment: Thanks for your explaination....Can you tell me what todo get the list of countries in the dropdown?

Comment: I was able to get the list of the countries back to the dropdown, after triggering a click on it, which makes it appear. See my code above. Is that acceptable to you?

Comment: I want the countries from the dropdown printed on my ide console?...currently only see the selected status(as per my code).

Comment: I got the countries printed on the console when i added that one new line to your original code. Did you try that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51203/discussion-between-user3296744-and-papacito)